# How regex remove only @ and . in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

what regex expression can I use to remove from email addresses the "@" and "." only?

I tried several variations and [this promissing one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-strip-invalid-characters-from-a-string) but didn't work.
thanks a bunch.

Comment: `var result = email.Replace("@", "").Replace(".", "");`

Comment: regex may be overrated ;) kidding ofc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use regular expressions for that

```
    string email = "user@domain.com";
    string result = Regex.Replace(email, @"[\.@]", "");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Explaining that... The first `@` means "ignore any escaping in this string" (it's a C# thing, not a regex thing, but since both C# and Regex use `\ ` (backslash) to escape characters, you need it).  The two square brackets say "consider any of the characters (or character ranges, not applicable here) as something I'm looking for.  The `\.` is an escaped dot.  The dot character is significant in the regex language (it represents "any character").  by escaping it, you make its meaning be "just a dot".  So, `[\.@]` means "consider either a dot or an at sign as something I'm looking for.